# What happens after the first one votes for close?

Tags: support, questions

Will moderators or high reputation users get a message or waits the system silently until the necessary number of close votes is reached ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Moderators and users with 10000 reputation (1000 during the beta) have access to some [moderation tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4565/what-are-the-moderation-tools-available-to-high-reputation-users), where – among other things – there is a list of posts with recent close votes.

There is no automatic notification, though – you have to actively go to that list to see them.

Comment: When I open a question example http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/310/converting-myisam-to-innodb currently I see (1) added to close, informing me that 1 user voted for close.

Comment: of course, non-moderators can also use the 'flag for moderator attention' if they think it's particularly bad, and then moderators *will* get a message (but I don't know if high-rep users will, too)

Comment: @Joe: No, flags for moderator attention are really only visible for moderators.